# Scrapy при экспорте в csv всё в одну строку

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, web-scraping

**получается так**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
article,size

9485,"40,41,43,45"

9494,"42,43,44"

,
```

**хотелось бы чтобы всё было в разных ячейках, как внизу на изображении**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
article;size
;
9485;"""40,41,43,45"""
;
9494;"""42,43,44"""
;
,;
```

**вот сам код**

```
import scrapy

class OutItem(scrapy.Item):
   size = scrapy.Field()
   article = scrapy.Field()



def parse(self, response):
    for div in response.xpath('//div[@class="right"]'):
        item = OutItem()
        item['size'] =div.xpath('//div[@class="option"]//div//label/text()').extract()
        item['article'] = div.xpath('//div[@class="description"]//div/text()').extract()

        yield item
```

**команда**

> scrapy crawl spidy -t csv -o spidy.csv --loglevel=INFO

**P.s заранее спасибо что уделили внимание**

Comment: спасибо что отозвались, я отредактировал

Comment: попытка номер два)

Comment: вывод выглядит нормально как есть. Когда вы в GUI открываете просто подходящий  csv диалект выберите. В качестве альтернативы, можно другой диалект сразу при экспорте использовать в scrapy. Связанный вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/q/42658875/4279

Comment: При открытии csv-шки укажи, что разделитель запятая а не точка с запятой.

Comment: не могли бы привести код как мне это сделать или пример, так нашёл решение но оно не удобное, на данном сайте http://normcsv.c3h.ru/

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй писать в файл через [pipeline](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html), и я бы советовал использовать tsv или csv. Pipeline нужно будет указать в settings и при запуске краулера из CLI указать только `scrapy crawl <SPIDER_NAME>`